# Nginx + NodeJs not working together

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am having troubles setting up NodeJs to work together with Nginx.

I have added forward of the subdomain to an IP address of my server. (when I ping subdomain it gives me the server IP address).

This is my config in **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name chat.mydomainname.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

My NodeJs server is running on port 3000 and I can access it via browser successfully on url **http://MYIPADDRESS:3000**

I noticed when I restart nginx server (**service nginx restart**) that I don't get any output that I usually should get.

I have tried to check what is on port 80 and does something blocks nginx from running. I killed those processes (which were all nginx) and I started it again, but no luck.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on Digital Ocean. (I have added subdomain on DigitalOcean also)

Can someone see some obvious mistake here?

Thanks!

Comment: Is selinux enabled?

Comment: @ianEllis I ran following command to check it:
```root@nodejs:/chatserver# sestatus
The program 'sestatus' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install policycoreutils```

Comment: where is `upstream` block in your config?

Comment: What does nginx -t output?

Comment: @Зелёный I haven't used `upstream`. NodeJs is running over `pm2`. I have used this manual `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04`

Comment: @IanEllis `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Comment: And curl localhost:3000 on server running nginx returns expected page?

Comment: @IanEllis it outputs the whole html page, so that is correct.

Comment: What about firewall? iptables -nL output?

Comment: @IanEllis 
```Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)```
`target     prot opt source               destination `

`Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)`
`target     prot opt source               destination         `

`Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)`
`target     prot opt source               destination `